# Scalatest & Easymock - not failing on empty expectations

Tags: scala, akka, easymock

I'm using scalatest and easymock 3.4. Tried some other versions. 
I'm having issues testing w/ akka using easymock.

Two strange behaviors:
Setting expectations worked if they are NOT called, but I can't get tests 
to fail if no expectations are set and the method is called.

Also I'm having these weird errors where it says the method is called as it's supposed to be! Why does this fail? Mocks are used inside an actor so there is obviously async activity involved. I can't seem to use verify :( I'm guessing this is somehow related to the async nature of akka.

[info]     java.lang.AssertionError: Expectation failure on verify:
[info]     YourInterface.poll(0, 100): expected: 1, actual: 1

Using all of the behavior in a test works but when introducing akka, I start seeing weird behavior making it hard to post code examples.

Comment: Can show us the code. Also, if you're testing something in Akka, why not use Akka testkit?

Comment: Hey Jason, I agree with @wheaties, can you distill this down to a simplified example demonstrating the issue so we can hack away on a solution?

Comment: ya I ended up giving up and using my own mock object but I'd like to find a good way to do this.